# Reactjs TextField helperText

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how can I synchronize error validation with the character limit without affecting its functions, please see this https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-mestorf-47jsvk?file=/src/App.js

```
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState(false);
  const CHARACTER_LIMIT = 1000;
  const [getString, setString]= useState({
    value: "",
    length: 0
  })


const onHandleChangeInput = (field, value) => {
  setString({value: value, length: value.length})
}
  const onHandleInputValidation = (field, value) => {
    try {
      Joi.assert(value, _.get(VALIDATION_SCHEMA, field));
      setFormError(_.omit(formError, field));
      return { error: false, valid: true };
    } catch (err) {
      return { error: err.message, valid: false };
    }
  };
    <TextField
      label="Name"
      inputProps={{
        maxlength: CHARACTER_LIMIT
      }}
      values={getString.name}
      onChange={(value) => onHandleChangeInput('name', value)}
      error={Boolean(formError.name)}
      helperText={{formError.name}, `${getString.length}/${CHARACTER_LIMIT}`}
    />
```

what i want is just like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onChange handler gets the `event`. You need to get the `value` out of it.

1. Update the `onHandleChangeInput` like below.

```
const onHandleChangeInput = (field, event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setString({ value: value, length: value.length });
    onHandleInputValidation(field, value);
};
```

2. name the parameter as `event` instead of `value` to be clear.

```
onChange={(event) => onHandleChangeInput("name", event)}
```

3. Use a ternary to show `error message` or `helperText`.

```
      helperText={
        Boolean(formError.name)
          ? formError.name
          : `${getString.length}/${CHARACTER_LIMIT}`
      }
```

Comment: how about the validation?

Comment: You can call the `onHandleInputValidation` from within `onHandleChangeInput` to do fire validations. If you create a mapping from `filed name` to `VALIDATION_SCHEMA` then these two functions are generic enough to used in any of the inputs

Comment: do i need to use two `helperText`? for validation of text and character limit?

Comment: you should use a ternary for that. only one will be displayed at a time. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const CHARACTER_LIMIT = 1000;
  const [getString, setString] = useState({
    value: "",
    length: 0
  });
  const onHandleChangeInput = (field, value) => {
    const { value: inputValue } = value.target;
    setString({ value: inputValue, length: inputValue.length });
  };
  return (
    <TextField
      label="Name"
      inputProps={{
        maxLength: CHARACTER_LIMIT
      }}
      values={getString.value}
      onChange={(e) => onHandleChangeInput("name", e)}
      error={Boolean(getString.length === CHARACTER_LIMIT)}
      helperText={`${getString.length}/${CHARACTER_LIMIT}`}
    />
  );
}
```

you are not using value from onChange as you were sending event then I extracted that value for you. Take a look

Comment: how about the validation?

Comment: isn't material-ui already taking care of that as you are using error prop in the textfield it will be showing input field in red also you can update CSS as you want using classes override

Answer (score 0):

You cannot exceed the charachter limit as long as you have not removed `inputProps={{ maxLength: CHARACTER_LIMIT }}`, after that you could use [`FormHelperText`](https://mui.com/api/form-helper-text/#main-content) component and pass two messages as follows:

```
<FormHelperText
  error={Boolean(formError.name)}
  sx={{
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    padding: '0 10px'
  }}
>
  <span>{formError.name}</span>
  <span>{`${getString.length}/${CHARACTER_LIMIT}`</span>
</FormHelperText>
```

[image: Edit mui FormHelperText two messages]